# Bash - Iterating through list of files provided as variable

Tags: bash

I have the following in my bash script:

```
local output_files=$(find "$output_folder" -type f)

for f in "$output_files"
do
  #do stuff
done
```

The above does not work when there is more than one file returned by the `find` command because the `\n` seems to be stripped when `$output_files` is evaluated in the for-loop, meaning that we only ever get one iteration of the for-loop because all filenames are concatenated into one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use a temporary variable, directly use `find` comment using `process substitution`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what your `#do stuff` is, you might as well use the `-exec` directive of `find`: example with the simple command `cat`:

```
find "$output_folder" -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

---

If you want to do something more complicated, the only safe way is:

```
find "$output_folder" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    #do stuff
done
```

Note that this implies that your version of `find` supports the `-print0` predicate (not all versions do, but GNU `find` does). Note also that the `while` loop is run in a subshell, so that any modifications to variables will be discarded after the loop. If this is a concern, you can use `shopt -s lastpipe` (Bash≥4.2, thanks @chepner) or a process substitution for the `find` command:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    #do stuff
done < <(find "$output_folder" -type f -print0)
```

Comment: In `bash` 4.2 or later, there's `shopt -s lastpipe` as well as an alternative to replacing the pipe with a process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4, you can avoid `find` altogether:

```
shopt -s globstar

for f in "$output_folder"/**/*; do
do
    [[ -f $f && ! -h $f ]] || continue  # -type f
     # dostuff
done
```

If you are more concerned with skipping directories than with strictly matching regular files (that is, you aren't considering the possibility of sockets, named pipes, etc in the hierarchy), you can use `[[ ! -d $f ]]` instead.

(The `-f` test will succeed for symlinks to regular files, while `-type f` would not. Use `-h`* to filter out symlinks to maintain as much compatibility with `-type f` as possible.)

This allows you to safely and cleanly handle all legal file names. (However, this is generally only an option if you aren't using other primaries with `find` that are harder to simulate in pure `bash`.)

---

* Or `-L`, which behaves identically to `-h`. The POSIX specification is silent as to why both exist; I suspect it is for backwards compatibility with existing implementations.

Comment: `+1` This is a good answer! though, there's a slight difference between the `-type f` predicate of `find` and the `-f` test of Bash: the case of a link to a regular file.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that distinction. I'll try to update my answer, but feel free to fix it if I get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `$outputfiles` in `for` loop.

```
for f in $output_files
do
  #do stuff
done
```

As @anubhava mentioned, you can also use `command substitution`.

```
for f in $(find "$output_folder" -type f)
do
  # do stuff
done
```

Comment: **Neither** of these is safe for filenames that contain whitespace or glob metacharacters. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) (specifically the parts about `-print0` for how to *safely* do this sort of thing.